# SolrQuery does not returns results for less than 3 characters

Tags: java, solr, solr-query-syntax

My code is as below:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(q.trim());
try {
        QueryResponse res = getSolrServer().query(query);
        return res.getResults();
    } catch (SolrServerException sse) {
        log.error(sse);
    }
```

The problem is that when i have a query more then 3 characters this returns me the response, e.g. query string "che" would respond with results, however the query string "ch" would return me no response.
Is there a way i can override the 3 character min length of Solr Query.

is the below xml causing the problem, if yes can i programmatically override it using java

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Appreciate the help in Advance.

Thanks and Regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: Solr would match what is being indexed. Probably you have a match for che and not for ch. Can you provide more insight on whats being indexed, how it is being indexed ?

Comment: che is just an example the problem is that anything more then 3 characters is searchable however a string less then 3 characters does not responds any results.

Comment: Whats your configuration for the field ? As there is no such configuration unless you are using LengthFilter in the analyzer chain.

Comment: can you provide me with one such example, appreciate your help on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NGramTokenizerFactory](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Tokenizers) :-
Default behavior. Note that this tokenizer operates over the whole field. It does not break the field at whitespace. As a result, the space character is included in the encoding.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

In: "hey man"

Out: "h", "e", "y", " ", "m", "a", "n", "he", "ey", "y ", " m", "ma", "an"

So with your configurations :- minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" the items less then 3 would be filtered

For two alphabets words, as you don't have the terms in the index these would never be searchable. You would need to change the minGramSize to 2 to make them searchable.

Comment: But can this be overridden in java code posted in the question?

Comment: nope as you don't have the terms in the index these would never be searchable. You would need to change the minGramSize to 2 to make them searchable.

Comment: can we switch the analyzers depending on the language, actually with language like chinese and japanese we want to provide search based on single character.

Comment: you can define different fields for each language and search on those fields according to the search language.